# HDFS file sink output as file stream input for another stream - race condition?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming

I'm evaluating a particular data-flow in a 15-node Spark cluster using structured streaming. I've defined 2 streaming queries in my application:

- SQ1 - Reads data from Kakfa -> processes -> writes to HDFS file sink (path - hdfs://tmp/output)
- SQ2 - Reads data as file stream from HDFS (same path as above) -> further processing -> writes to external database using ForeachWriter

Both queries are set to trigger every 15 seconds.

My question - am I looking at a race condition here, where SQ2 picks up the partially written files (which are generated by SQ1) from HDFS? A more general question would be, is the file sink writer for HDFS "atomic"? I've tried to dig through the streaming source code in Spark but haven't made much progress.

Comment: Per the Spark Streaming documentation, [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html), it seems that writing files to HDFS is non-atomic, i.e. SQ2 will pick up files that are partially written.

Comment: Specifically, the documentation states that: "Full” Filesystems such as HDFS tend to set the modification time on their files as soon as the output stream is created. When a file is opened, even before data has been completely written, it may be included in the DStream - after which updates to the file within the same window will be ignored. That is: changes may be missed, and data omitted from the stream.

Comment: Did you find any solution to the race condition?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of this approach is that all File Sinks (such as HDFS) in Spark Structured Streaming can only operate in *append* mode. In addition, reading from a file is done as soon as the file has been created. Any subsequent updates or finalization of writes will be ignored.

According to the book "Learning Spark - 2nd Edition" on reading from files

> "each file must appear in the directory listing atomically - that is, the whole file must be available at once for reading, and once it is available, the file cannot be updated or modified."
>
> "[Writing to files] ... it only supports append mode, because while it is easy to write new files in the output directory (i.e., append data to a directory), it is hard to modify existing data files (as would be expected with update and complete modes)."

To overcome the issue you are facing you could change your streaming queries to something like:

- SQ1 - Reads data from Kafka -> processes -> further processing  -> cache/persist
- SQ2a writes cached DataFrame to HDFS file sink (path - hdfs://tmp/output)
- SQ2b writes cached DataFrame to external database using ForeachWriter
  -> writes to external database using ForeachWriter